# Android: Menu slider with multiple lists

Tags: android, listview, navigation, slidingdrawer, drawer

Can someone help me with this error ?

[XDA Developer thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2638239)

I want to use navigation drawer ...but not simple one. but similar to this one

> [image]

How can I have list of items below it item 1 item 1, then have header list of houses  house  house 2 house 3 below it ?

Comment: it supports only one list view

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawer only supports one listview. However, you can support headers within your list view using the standard Android `ListView` class. You need to override `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` to supply different view types. In your case, you would have one type (layout) for the header and one for the list items.

Comment: how can I do that? That is have inside onelistview multiple headers.  header  below it item 1 item 2... then header 2 below it item 3 item 4 item 5... all one listview

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with height of first list view:

try this:

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
     <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_menuslider"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Comment: it will not help..
as it support one list view only

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in new xml for header
name it **list_header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome_text_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_slider_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="...................."
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Write following code to your Activity:-

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup mTop = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.header_listview_menue, mDrawerList, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(mTop, null, false);
        txt_slider_user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_slider_user);
```